# How many homomorphisms are there of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've tried looking around for an explanation to this problem, but I've been having trouble finding a clear solution that specifically focuses on this question:

How many homomorphisms are there of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ into $\Bbb Z$?

I'm studying abstract algebra and we have just begun discussing rings. Thank you in advance for your help. I would appreciate it if you could give me step by step help for this problem. This is not for homework- I just need to figure out how to do this problem to prepare for my exam. Thanks!

Edit: Here is a post that addressed the question, but did not answer it fully: [Describe all ring homomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380843/describe-all-ring-homomorphisms?newreg=12e3dc01d37f4a8e813f61c8e01499f2)

Comment: Are you regarding $\mathbb{Z}^3$ as a module, or as a ring?

Comment: See the above edit- the question comes from a series of questions about ring homomorphisms, but this part of the question is left kind of ambiguous. I guess that's part of my question, too.

Comment: A ring, not a module.

Comment: One should never forget that a $\Bbb Z$-linear map $f:\Bbb Z^n\to\Bbb Z^m$ is given by a matrix of size $m\times n$ with integer coordinates, and uniquely so.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the question is about ring homomorphisms, there are $3$. Here is how to see this very explicitly.

Write $e_1 = (1, 0, 0), e_2 = (0, 1, 0), e_3 = (0, 0, 1)$. These three elements form a *complete set of orthogonal idempotents*. This means that they satisfy $e_i e_j = \delta_{ij} e_j$ and $\sum e_i = 1$, or more explicitly

$$e_i^2 = e_i, e_i e_j = 0 \text{ if } i \neq j, e_1 + e_2 + e_3 = 1.$$

The significance of these conditions for us is that they must be preserved by ring homomorphisms. Hence if $f : \mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring homomorphism, $f(e_i)$ is a complete set of orthogonal idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}$. It's clear that $f$ is determined by the $f(e_i)$.

But $\mathbb{Z}$ only has two idempotents, namely $0$ and $1$. The condition that $\sum f(e_i) = 1$ means exactly one of the $f(e_i)$ is equal to $1$, and then orthogonality is automatic. Hence there are $3$ homomorphisms corresponding to whether $f(e_1), f(e_2)$, or $f(e_3)$ is $1$; these are the $3$ projection maps $\mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}$.

More generally, homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}^m$ correspond to functions $m \to n$.

The algebraic significance of complete sets of orthogonal idempotents in a commutative ring $R$ is that they correspond to decompositions of $R$ as a finite product $\prod_i R e_i$ of rings. The geometric significance is that they correspond to decompositions of $\text{Spec } R$ into a finite disjoint union $\coprod_i \text{Spec } R e_i$ of affine schemes. Here $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}^n$ decomposes into $n$ copies of $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Good answer! $\;$

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I was looking for.

Comment: The condition that $\sum f(e_i)=1$ alone actually tells you exactly one of the $f(e_i)$ is $1$.

Comment: @Eric: whoops. Yes, of course.

Comment: I don't quite understand the $Re_i$ thing in the last paragraph. Does this just mean $\prod_{i \in I} R$?

Comment: @goblin: no. The $e_i$ are a complete system of orthogonal idempotents and $R e_i$ means the ideal generated by $e_i$.

Comment: Oh okay. I think get it: basically, $e_i$ becomes the unit of $Re_i$. Is that right?

Comment: @goblin: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that the question is about module homomorphisms, not ring homomorphisms.)

Adam is right. In more detail:

> **Definition/Proposition.**
>
> Suppose we're given
>
> - a commutative ring with unity, call it $R$,
> - an $R$-module, call it $X$,
> - a finite set $S$.
>
> Then there's a natural bijective correspondence between:
>
> - homomorphisms $X \leftarrow R^S$ and
> - functions $X \leftarrow S.$
>
> given as follows:
>
> Firstly, assign to each $s \in S$ a vector $e_s \in R^S$ writing by $e_s(s') = [s=s']$, where $[]$ is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).
>
> $(\Rightarrow)$ Given a homomorphism $h : X \leftarrow R^S$, we get a function $F(h) : X \leftarrow S$ defined as follows: $$F(h)(s) = h(e_s).$$
>
> $(\Leftarrow)$ Given a function $f : X \leftarrow S$, we get a homomorphism $H(f) : X\leftarrow R^S$ by writing: $$H(f)(a) = \sum_{s \in S} a(s)f(s)$$
>
> (The above sum makes sense because $S$ is finite.)

To prove this:

**Step 0.** Check that $H(f)$ really is a homomorphism.

**Step 1.** Check that these processes are inverse to each other. That is:

$$H(F(h)) = h, \qquad F(H(f)) = f$$

**Step 2.** (Optional). If you know some category theory, you can also go ahead and try to prove that $H$ and $F$ are natural transformations.

Comment: Although there are moral reasons to write down arrows in functions the way you do, there are social reasons one would like to avoid it. Is it really a notation that carries a significant advantage?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I really haven't decided yet. Sometimes I flip back and forth between them. The thing that made me use the backward $R \leftarrow S$ here is the agreement with the $R^S$ notation. But anyway, I don't really care about the social reasons, or tradition. As a general rule, I think we take these kinds of things altogether too seriously. What I want is to settle on a truly optimal system of conventions to hand to the next generation.