# Find all homomorphism $\Phi : \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

Knowing $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic can I infer that $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic aswell?

I know I can assume this statement to be true for finite cyclic groups but is there a infinite case to this theorem?

How can I find all homomorphisms beside the trivial one:  $\phi \equiv 0$?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_n\oplus \Bbb Z_m$ needs not be cyclic!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic.

Comment: If   $\mathbb{Z} \bigoplus \mathbb{Z}$ is not cyclic can I infer that there are no homomorphisms $\phi$ as requested?

Comment: There are certainly the two projections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any such will be determined by $h(1,0)=m$ and $h(0,1)=n$, and vice-versa, since $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z=\langle (1,0),(0,1)\rangle $.

Thus $\operatorname {hom}(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2795441/403337).

Note:  $\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z$ isn't cyclic,  since its homomorphic image $\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_2$ isn't.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly. 
Can I say that all homomorphism are described as : 
$\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} : \phi (a,b) = a*m + b*n$

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.

Answer (score 4):

On account of the universal property of the direct sum, you get $\operatorname{hom}(\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)\simeq \operatorname{hom}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)\times \operatorname{hom}(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)\simeq \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$. Here the last isomorphism is obtained by sending a homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ to $\phi(1)$.