# Find all ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I want to find all rings homomorphisms from:

i) $$\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$$

ii)  $$\mathbb{Z}_m\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$$

iii) $$\mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$$

---

I don't know how to work this exercise, can someone explain to me how we think about these types of questions?

For the first one I only found $2$ the trivial and $\varphi(m)=m \pmod{n} $

for ii) I think of the trivial and $\varphi(m)=m $

and for iii) I found the trivial and $\varphi(m)=am, a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ such that $na=0 \pmod{m}$

Comment: They are all cyclic groups, so if you can focus on where a generator goes, you can find everything else easily.

Comment: Homomorphisms of what? Homomorphisms of groups are not the same as homomorphisms of rings.

Comment: @WhatsUp I think OP means group homomorphism (from the tags).

Comment: @AnuragA I think WhatsUp means it ought to be explicitly stated.

Comment: guided by the tags, should be for groups, but the 1st of them cover for rings too, what about include, on the answers, both cases?

Comment: @AnuragA Actually that tag (and also `group-theory` and `cyclic-groups`) is added by user Shaun, rather than by the OP.

Comment: That's true, @AnuragA.

Comment: Sorry, @WhatsUp.

Comment: @WhatsUp you are right and I am not saying that OP should not have included that information. However I was also thinking, what if OP has no idea of what a ring is? In that case OP would not even feel the need of clarifying that because he/she may not even be aware of the fact that other homomorphisms are also out there. Not sure what's the proper way to address a situation like this.

Comment: There are many types of homeomorphisms. Here, are you talking about homeomorphisms of rings or groups?

Comment: This must be a duplicate thread.

Comment: I am sorry for not been specific, I meant rings homomorphism.

Comment: Based on your attempts, I assume your "rings" may be non-unital (i.e. rngs) and therefore the homomorphisms need not respect multiplicative identities?  Compare with the properties in [the ring homomorphism Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Describe all ring homomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380843/describe-all-ring-homomorphisms)

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: ring homomorphisms send 1 to 1.

The only possible ring homomorphism of type i) is $\varphi(n) = \overline{n}$ - the canonical projection, for $\mathbb{Z}$ is the initial object in the category of rings.

For ring homomorphisms of type ii), note that if $\varphi(\overline{1}) = k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $n \varphi(\overline{1}) = 0$, which means $\varphi$ is the $0$ function. If you require that ring homomorphisms send 1 to 1, then there are no such ring homomorphisms.

For iii), we have that $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ must factor through $\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ - which means that $(n) \subseteq (m)$ - i.e., $m$ divides $n$.